# Getting markdown email as a plain text

Tags: markdown, lumen

I am using laravel Mailable and markdown to send an email but it send an email like below,
not getting what I am doing wrong.

```
Hello cus1
    Please click the button below to verify your email address.

    <table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="https://google.com" class="button button-primary"
                                       target="_blank">Verify Email Address</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    If you did not create an account, no further action is required.

    Thanks,<br>
    PMS
```

[image]

Below is my `welcome_email.blade.php` used to generate email template

```
@component('mail::message')
    # Hello {{ $user->name }},

    Please click the button below to verify your email address.

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => $verificationUrl])
        Verify Email Address
    @endcomponent

    If you did not create an account, no further action is required.

    Thanks,<br>
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 11):

You should try removing the indentation inside the blade file. Sometimes the markdown gets crazy because of that.

Try something like this:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Hello {{ $user->name }},

Please click the button below to verify your email address.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => $verificationUrl])
Verify Email Address
@endcomponent

If you did not create an account, no further action is required.

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```